# Elements for building secure site

Tags: php, asp.net, security

If i was to build a "Hacker proof" site what would be my weapons of choice? 
I guess wordpress is out of the question. ;)

I am fully aware that it is no such thing as hacker proof but lets say i wanted to delay for as long as possible.

Maybe you can give me some pointers on how to proceed with that and some do´s and dont´s.

Thank you.

Comment: "The best defense is a good offense". I mean, to improve the security of your site, first you need to understand what are the most common attacks. I suggest you to start with code injection and XSS, you can find many topics here in stackoverflow.

Comment: also depends what you need to protect, what people can do on the site. more details would be needed.

Comment: Lets say i build it with WP. Would it be sufficient to change table prefix? To something like 143h135h5532j5j_ instead of: wp_ for ex.  

If i build with WP would would be other things to think about?

Answer (score 1):

The question is very broad, but some essentials:

- Prevent SQL Injection by using prepared statements.
- Validate input / Output to prevent XSS
- CSRF protection for form data
- HTTPS for secure login pages
- Secure permissions for web processes / folders on your server
- Up to date software on server
- Backups to remote server
- Fail2Ban to prevent brute forcing
- Montior access / error logs from apache/nginx
- Monit for resource montioring
- Encrypt passwords using a secure hashing algorithm that can't be brute forced
- Two Factor authentication

Those are the ones off the top of my head.

Comment: Yes i know it is a very broad question.  Those are great pointers. Thanx! Do you have example of some sort of CMS that could be used?

Comment: Honestly I would just use WordPress. Yes, every now and then a security issue pops up,but if you keep it up to date you shouldn't have many problems.

Comment: That´s what i really would like to use. I have looked at secure CMS´s and the cost for it is astronomic.